# How can I get the checkForWinner function to set the correct player correctly in this Tic Tac Toe game?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In this tic tac toe game, the function `checkForWinner` should check each button and determine if either `Player.X` won the game or `Player.O`. The function does not determine a winner until after both players have moved. The code should work by determining winners after each move of the player and not only after both have moved. How can I correct this code in `checkForWinner`?

````
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.selection.selectable
import androidx.compose.foundation.selection.selectableGroup
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.RadioButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Companion.CenterHorizontally
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.tictactoe.ui.theme.TicTacToeTheme
import kotlin.random.Random


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TicTacToeTheme {
                var selectedOption = remember { RadioButtonState() }
                ButtonGrid(selectedOption)
//                PlayerRow()
            }
        }


    }
}

class RadioButtonState() {
    var players by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
}

@Composable
fun PlayerRow(selectedOption: RadioButtonState = remember {
    RadioButtonState()
}, onResetClicked: () -> Unit) {
    val radioOptions = listOf("One Player", "Two Players")
//    var selectedOption

    Row(
        Modifier
            .selectableGroup()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 20.dp)
            .height(20.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
//        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        radioOptions.forEach { text ->
            Row(
                Modifier
//                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (text == selectedOption.players),
                        onClick = { selectedOption.players = text },
                        role = Role.RadioButton
                    ),
//                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
//                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    selected = (text == selectedOption.players),
//                    enabled = (text == radioOptions[0]),
                    onClick = null
                )
                Spacer(Modifier.size(4.dp))
                Text(text = text)
            }
        }
    }
    Row(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
            onClick = {
                selectedOption.players = null
                onResetClicked()
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Reset")
        }
    }
}

enum class Player {
    NONE, X, O
}

fun makeAIMove(cells: MutableList<Player>) {
    val availableMoves = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in cells.indices) {
        if (cells[i] == Player.NONE) {
            availableMoves.add(i)
        }
    }
    if (availableMoves.isNotEmpty()) {
        val randomIndex = Random.nextInt(availableMoves.size)
        val moveIndex = availableMoves[randomIndex]
        cells[moveIndex] = Player.O
    }
}

fun checkForWinner(cells: List<Player>): Player {
    val winningCombinations = listOf(
        listOf(0, 1, 2),  // Rows
        listOf(3, 4, 5),
        listOf(6, 7, 8),
        listOf(0, 3, 6),  // Columns
        listOf(1, 4, 7),
        listOf(2, 5, 8),
        listOf(0, 4, 8),  // Diagonals
        listOf(2, 4, 6)
    )

    for (combination in winningCombinations) {
        val (a, b, c) = combination
        if (cells[a] != Player.NONE && cells[a] == cells[b] && cells[b] == cells[c]) {
            return cells[a] // Return the winning player
        }
    }

    return Player.NONE // No winner found
}

@Composable
fun ButtonGrid(selectedOption: RadioButtonState = remember {
    RadioButtonState()
}, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var currentPlayer by remember { mutableStateOf(Player.X) }
    var gameInProgress by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val cells = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            Player.NONE, Player.NONE, Player.NONE,
            Player.NONE, Player.NONE, Player.NONE,
            Player.NONE, Player.NONE, Player.NONE
        )
    }

    val winner = checkForWinner(cells)
//    }

    if (winner != Player.NONE) {
        gameInProgress = false
        Text(
            text = "Winner: ${winner.name}",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
        )
    }



    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Text(
            text = "Current Player: ${currentPlayer.name}",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(CenterHorizontally)
                .padding(16.dp)
        )

        for (row in 0 until 3) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                for (column in 0 until 3) {
                    val index = row * 3 + column
                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(4.dp)
                            .size(64.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10),
                        onClick = {
                            if (/*gameInProgress && */cells[index] == Player.NONE) {
                                cells[index] = currentPlayer
                                if (selectedOption.players == "Two Players") {
                                    currentPlayer =
                                        if (currentPlayer == Player.X) Player.O else Player.X
                                }
                                else if (selectedOption.players == "One Player" && gameInProgress) {
                                    makeAIMove(cells)
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        enabled = cells[index] == Player.NONE && gameInProgress
                    ) {
                        Text(text = if (cells[index] == Player.NONE) "" else cells[index].name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PlayerRow(selectedOption) {
                cells.fill(Player.NONE)
                currentPlayer = Player.X
                gameInProgress = true
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I simply used a delegate.

```
var winner by remember { mutableStateOf(Player.NONE) }
winner = checkForWinner(cells)
```